# PHP error_log from CLI

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I'm calling a php script using CRON.

The script use a lot the error_log function :

```
error_log('My error');
```

Seems like it's not working from CLI.

I can make it work by using more arguments :

```
error_log('My error', 3, '/fullpath/to/my/log');
```

But I would like to avoid modifying everything (my script include a lot of other scripts).

As far as I understand, PHP is using a different php.ini when called from command line.

Is there a way to force it to use the normal php.ini ?

I need my cron to execute this script in the exact same environment that from the web.

Are there problems I should be aware of ? Others differences that could break my code ?

**Edit :**

I found a way to tell php which php.ini file to use (-c):

```
/path/to/php5 -c /path/to/php.ini /path/to/script.php
```

But it's not working.
In my script `shell_exec('php --ini')` is still showing cli/php.ini...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need your cron to execute this script in the **exact same environment** that from the web, just call it from *the web*:

- setup a virtual host (local only, e.g. on port 4242, locked with iptables)
- run cron as `curl http://localhost:4242/script.php`

It will run the script as a webserver user, using all environment variables, configs, and logs.

To solve the exact problem with logging, just redirect `stderr` to a file:

```
/path/to/php5  /path/to/script.php 2> /fullpath/to/my/log
```

The lst part: `shell_exec('php --ini')` shows default cli/php.ini because you start new process with default config. To show custom config either specify it in the command line

```
shell_exec('php --ini -c /path/to/php.ini')
```

or show info for current process:

```
phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)
```

Comment: The script is outside root path to avoid it being called by users. But if I can't resolve this i'll follow your advice. Everything should be fine with just php -c...

Comment: If you give up with stderr redirection, read the bullet points in the answer how to setup it properly to avoid being called by users.

Comment: Oh, I can see now the stupidity of what I did. Cron called with good php.ini, but inside of it shell exec have no -c flag... Took me so much time to see the light ^^